# Is it possible make approximate estimation of variables values when having only differences?!

Tags: arithmetic

I hope guys here don't judge people by their first question :)

For a naive, like me, I don't know what this problem formal name might be or even if this a worthy problem, but hopefully this won't deter anyone with knowledge from providing guidance.

Assuming we have the following quantities :

$$ x= a-b $$
$$ y= a-c $$
$$ z= b-c $$

**is it possible to get an approximate estimation of any of $a, b, c$. Or perhaps get a formula where only one of them dominates ?**

Comment: What do you mean by "a formula where only one of them dominates"?

Comment: @EricWofsey I don't have very specific thing in mind, but if I have, for example, $a^4+b-c$ , then $a$ has larger weight than the others, right?

Comment: Not if $a$ is small (like $0.01$); then it has almost no weight. But I want to respond to your initial point: this is *absolutely* a good question, and you asked it pretty well. There's no shame in not knowing the answer -- that's why we're here! (You don't need to use bold for the question, though -- we'll find it all by ourselves, by looking for the "?". :)  One more thing: if you've played with a question a little bit, it's nice to also say "Here's what I've come up with so far" -- that lets us know something about your level of mathematical sophistication, so we can answer appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$ alone do not allow you to even approximately determine any of the numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$.  First, note that $x+z=(a-b)+(b-c)=a-c=y$, so $y$ tells you no information that $x$ and $z$ do not already tell you.

Now given values of $x$ and $z$, let $d$ be any number.  If we define $c=d$, $b=d+z$ and $a=d+x+z$, notice that these three numbers will satisfy $x=a-b$ and $z=b-c$ (and also $y=a-c$ if $y=x+z$).  So given the values of $x$ and $z$, $c$ could be *any number at all* (whatever we want to choose $d$ to be).  Similarly, $a$ and $b$ could each also be any number at all by changing $d$.

So if you know $x$ and $z$, you can't say anything about any of the numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ individually.  You just know something about how they are related to each other (namely, what the differences between them are).